# Mechanics of the Javascript rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript

Okay so something has been bugging me and I haven't been able to find the answer. So here's Codeacademy's rock, paper, scissors game:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2){

if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
}

else if(choice1 === "rock") {

if(choice2 === "scissors") {
    return "rock wins";
}
else {
    return "paper wins";
    }
}

else if(choice1 === "paper") {
    if(choice2 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins"
    }
else {
    return "scissors wins"
    }
}

else if(choice1 === "scissors") {
    if(choice2 === "rock") {
        return "rock wins"
}
    else {
        return "scissors wins"
    }
}
};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Now what I am wondering is, is how does the computer know what choice1 and choice2 is when it uses it for the if/else loop that determines the winner? Is it declared on the userChoice and computerChoice functions and if so how? Links to any documentation would be helpful. I am just trying to understand how exactly JavaScript works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compare` is a function that takes `choice1` and `choice2` as its arguments.  Their values are determined when the function is called.  For example, if you have 2 variables `foo` and `bar` containing strings like this:

```
var foo = 'rock';
var bar = 'paper';
```

and you call `compare` passing those 2 variables, like so:

```
compare(foo, bar);
```

then, inside `compare`, `choice1` will be `'foo'` and `choice2` will be `'bar'`.

For strings, this is exactly the same as calling `compare` like this:

```
compare('rock', 'paper');
```

If you look at the rest of the codecademy example you will see a call to `compare` further down.

Comment: Thank you Alex for that detailed and helpful answer. I should have made the connection between the compare at the end and how the variables were created with that whole if/else function. I'm still working on getting the hang of how things are ordered and such in JavaScript. I'll keep practicing and hopefully it'll come easier soon. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

`choice1` and `choice2` are arguments of the function `compare()`, so they take the value you pass to the function when you call it.

You call the compare function at the end of your script, using `compare(userChoice, computerChoice);`. So `choice1` will have value of `userChoice` and `choice2` will have value of `computerChoice`.

`computerChoice` is determined random at the start, and `userChoice` by the user input